# Template Issue of Views.py

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. So I am trying to add a HTML template to the `views.py` but it is showing an error, it would be great if you would help me.

The full Error that I am seeing:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
platform/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
platform/home.html
Exception Location: C:\Users\Adeel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Adeel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Adeel\\Google Drive\\Visual Studio\\Personal Portfolio\\Portfolio',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Adeel\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Tue, 13 Oct 2020 06:14:44 +0000
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'platform/home.html')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from Platform import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name='Home'),
]
```

settings.py:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{       
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',

        ],
    },
},
]
```

My HTML template that i am trying to add:

```
<h1>This is my project</h1>
```

Comment: Exactly where is the template located?

Comment: i have created a separate folder in my Platform App of the project

Comment: Please show the full error message - it will tell you the directories Django searched for the template.

Comment: @AdeelSheikh: you will need to add the separate folder to the `DIRS` settings.

Comment: show full error message and show how you structured your project

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the template to your directories

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your/way/to/templates'),
        ],
        ...
]
```

After that

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Hope I didn't miss anything

**EDIT**

You should have a separate folder with templates

and in urls.py

```
from . import views
```